# WebRTC: setting up environment for TURN connectivity case testing

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I am working on WebRTC application (C++/Linux) which will use both STUN+TURN server (coturn) to guarantee the possibility to establish connection between two peers. However I haven’t faced a case when I wasn’t able to establish connection using the only STUN server. So I cannot be sure that  application and server environment works correctly.
How to set the environment where direct communication is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can either block UDP using whatever packet filter is on your system which will force your application to fallback to a TURN/TCP or TURN/TCP server.

Or you can set the RTCPeerConnection's [iceTransportPolicy](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcicetransportpolicy-enum) to `relay` which will force the connection to emit only relay candidates.